# Unparseable date : "20180......" Json date to java

Tags: java, json, date, parsing, converters

I'm trying to parse a date in json format like this `"20180130000000"`,
and the program sends me this exception do you have any idea how to do this?
Here is my code :

```json
{
   "monTableau": [
      {
         "Données": "ONE",
         "Date import": "20180130000000",
         "Date export": "20180130000000"
      },
      {
         "Données": "TWO",
         "Date import": "20190101000000",
         "Date export": "20190101000000"
      },
      {
         "Données": "THREE",
         "Date import": "20200101000000",
         "Date export": "20200101000000"
      },
      {
         "Données": "FOUR",
         "Date import": "20180130000000",
         "Date export": "20180130000000"
      }
   ]
}
```

```java
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JSONParser jsonP = new JSONParser();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

        try {
            JSONObject jsonO = (JSONObject) jsonP.parse(new FileReader("C:/myJsonTest.json"));
            JSONArray myArray = (JSONArray) jsonO.get("monTableau");

            for (int i=0;i<myArray.size();i ++){
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) myArray.get(i);
                String donnees = (String) jo.get("Données");
                String dateImport = (String) jo.get("Date import");
                Date date = df.parse(dateImport);
                String dateExport = (String) jo.get("Date export");
                System.out.println("Donnees : "+donnees);
                //System.out.println("Date import : "+date);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a datetime of the format `"20180130000000"` could be parsed with the pattern `"dd-MMM-yy"`? Do you have to use `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or can you switch to `java.time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your date formatter with the pattern `dd-MMM-yy`. But your input it completely different. You have to adjust the pattern according to your input.

Try a different pattern like:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```